# ivec2 is not defined at webgl slider with gl transition

Tags: javascript

I'm using a webgl slider that is using different transitions and you can also use your own transitions. The transitions used are from  https://gl-transitions.com/ and the one I want to use is this one:
https://gl-transitions.com/editor/randomsquares

The problem is that I get **ivec2 undefined error**...
New to webgl...

I've managed implement other effects but I don't understand how to handle ivec2. Is it an array?

```
const uniforms = {
    size: ivec2(10, 10),
    smoothness: 0.5
};

const shader = [
    'uniform ivec2 size; // = ivec2(10, 10)',
    'uniform float smoothness; // = 0.5',

    'float rand (vec2 co) {',
      'return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);',
    '}',

    'vec4 transition(vec2 p) {',
      'float r = rand(floor(vec2(size) * p));',
      'float m = smoothstep(0.0, -smoothness, r - (progress * (1.0 + smoothness)));',
      'return mix(getFromColor(p), getToColor(p), m);',
    '}'
].join( '\n' );
GLSlideshow.addShader( 'myShader', shader, uniforms );

loader.whenReady = function() {
    var slideshow = new GLSlideshow(
        [ 'img/1.jpg', 'img/2.jpg', 'img/3.jpg', 'img/4.jpg' ],
        {
            canvas: document.getElementById( 'myCanvas' ), // optional
            width: 1024,        // optional
            height: 576,        // optional
            duration: 5000,     // optional
            interval: 3000,     // optional
            effect: 'myShader'
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: that second line `size: ivec2(10, 10)` is from some library and has nothing to do with WebGL. It has to do with the library you're using or your own code. You might be better off asking [here](https://github.com/gl-transitions/gl-transitions/issues). Have you tried `size: [10, 10]`?

Comment: @gman
yes I've tried size: [10, 10] - but with no luck...
Then I get an webgl-error...
[.WebGL-0x7f8e70892000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glUniform2fv: wrong uniform function for type

Comment: use `size: [10, 10]` and change every `ivec2` to `vec2` in the shader. [Looking at the source](https://github.com/yomotsu/gl-slideshow/blob/846b554c7667327d63bfbd205297d2b669480168/src/GLSlideshow.ts) there is no support for `ivec2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking at the source](Looking at the source) there is no support for ivec2.

Further that second line `size: ivec2(10, 10)` is from some library or is some code you write and has nothing to do with WebGL. There is no such thing as `ivec2` in JavaScript so. It has to do with the library you're using or your own code.

Simple solution, use `size: [10, 10]` and change every `ivec2` to `vec2` in the shader.

```js
const uniforms = {
    size: [10, 10],
    smoothness: 0.5
};

const shader = `
    uniform vec2 size; // = vec2(10, 10)
    uniform float smoothness; // = 0.5

    float rand (vec2 co) {
      return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
    }

    vec4 transition(vec2 p) {
      float r = rand(floor(vec2(size) * p));
      float m = smoothstep(0.0, -smoothness, r - (progress * (1.0 + smoothness)));
      return mix(getFromColor(p), getToColor(p), m);
    }
`;
GLSlideshow.addShader( 'myShader', shader, uniforms );


// since we can't use images because gl-slideshow doesn't support CORS
// let's use canvases


    var slideshow = new GLSlideshow(
        [ 
          makeImage('A', 'red', 'cyan'),
          makeImage('B', 'green', 'magenta'),
          makeImage('C', 'blue', 'yellow'),
          makeImage('D', 'black', 'white'),
        ],
        {
            canvas: document.getElementById( 'myCanvas' ), // optional
            duration: 1000,     // optional
            interval: 2000,     // optional
            effect: 'myShader'
        }
    );
    
    
// ----------------------------

function makeImage(str, bg, fg) {
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width = 128;
  ctx.canvas.height = 128;
  ctx.fillStyle = bg;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
  ctx.fillStyle = fg;
  ctx.font = "bold 110px sans-serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText(str, 64, 64);
  return ctx.canvas.toDataURL();  // gl-slideshow doesn't handle canvas so we need to make a data URL
}
```

```html
<script src="http://unpkg.com/GLSlideshow@2.1.0/dist/gl-slideshow.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```